# Copy Sheet data from 1 sheet to other sheet in same workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Basically i need to copy the rows and cols which are not fixed, so it can increase daily from one sheet to another sheet in the same workbook.

I am getting error in the end as

> "Run-time error '5' Invalid procedure call or argument

Below is the vba code:

```
Sub consolidate()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wsAll As Worksheet
    Set wsAll = wb.Worksheets("All")
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("S1")
    Dim lastRowAll As Long
    Dim lastRow1 As Long
    Dim lastCol1 As Long
    
    
    lastRowAll = wsAll.Cells(wsAll.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    lastRow1 = ws1.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    lastCol1 = ws1.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
    ws1.Activate
    
    Cells(lastRow1, lastCol1).Copy
    
    wsAll.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Cells("A" & lastRowAll).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    
    MsgBox ("Job Complete!!")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line `ActiveSheet.Cells("A" & lastRowAll).Select` You can't pass string address to Cell you muss pass row and column number like `ActiveSheet.Cells(1 ,1).Select` or you can use Range instead `ActiveSheet.Range("A" & lastRowAll).Select).Select`
Also notice you're using Cells(lastRow1, lastCol1).Copy. This is copying only the last cell in the "S1" worksheet, not all cells.

Code bellow should help you achive what you need

```
Sub consolidate()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wsAll As Worksheet
    Set wsAll = wb.Worksheets("All")
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("S1")
    Dim lastRowAll As Long
    Dim lastRow1 As Long
    Dim lastCol1 As Long
    
    lastRowAll = wsAll.Cells(wsAll.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    lastRow1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol1 = ws1.Cells(1, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(1, 1), ws1.Cells(lastRow1, lastCol1)).Copy wsAll.Cells(lastRowAll, 1)
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    MsgBox ("Job Complete!!")
End Sub
```